# @JSON annotation to replace a String value with null in Java

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am looking for an annotation I can use to replace String value to null in Java

There are some @Json annotation that can do customization while serializing a JSON object to POJO,

I want to do something like this:

```
@JsonFormat(<if incoming value is SOMESTRING>, <set incoming value to null>)
String valueChangedUsingAnnotation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@JsonIgnore` annotation. This annotation is used when you want to ignore certain properties of a java class. It will ignore those fields annotated with when reading from json to java object and also, writing java object to json.

Answer (score 1):

If incoming value is SOMETHING, set its value to null. For this you can **update the setter method of that particular field** in POJO class. Because, when incoming object is deserialized it invokes setter methods of each fields.

Something like below:

```
class Test{

//constructor, other fields and their getters and setters

private String target;

public void setTarget(String target) {
if(target.equals("abcd"){
   this.target=null
}
else {
    this.target=target;
  } 
} 
}
```

There is no need of any JSON annotations.